# What flag should I use to exclude file types from synchronization with rclone?

Tags: rclone

I have a list of file types to exclude from syncing. But, due to its strange nature, I don't know which flag is appropriate

file exclude.txt

```
encryptable
Zone.identifier
.fuse_hidden*
goutputstream*
.spotlight-*
.fseventsd*
.ds_store*
~lock.*
Thumbs.db
attributes
```

command:

```
rclone sync upload_local gdrive:upload --verbose --update --modify-window 1h --no-update-modtime --transfers 30 --checkers 8 --contimeout 60s --timeout 300s --retries 3 --low-level-retries 10 --stats 1s --stats-file-name-length 0 --exclude-from exclude.txt --log-file=rclone.log
```

or you should use: "--exclude-regexp" or "--filter-from"

PD: but there is something very strange.

with `--exclude-from exclude.txt` it does not work

with `--filter-from exclude.txt` it does not work (putting "-" at the beginning of the line)

with `--exclude *Zone.Identifier` ... it does not work

with `--exclude *.fuse_hidden` ... works

with `--exclude *Zone.identifier* --exclude *.fuse_hidden* --ignore-case` ... works

**Update: works**

Finally, the list works, as long as all the lines have wildcards and as @petitradisgris points out, `--ignore-case` was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the `--exclude-from` flag in this case.It allows you to provide a text file containing a list of patterns to exclude during syncing (including wildcards like *) .

Using `--exclude-regexp` or `--filter-from` might not be appropriate in this case as they are used for more complex filtering patterns and may not be necessary for your specific example.

**Beware of the names for Zone.identifier (in your *exclude.txt*) VS your actual file *Zone.Identifier* (I uppercase vs lowercase).** With the `--ignore-case` flag enabled, rclone will match exclusion patterns using case-insensitive matching, so "example.txt", "EXAMPLE.TXT", and "ExAmple.TXt" will all be excluded during the sync operation.

So your rclone command would look like:

```
rclone sync upload_local gdrive:upload --verbose --update --modify-window 1h --no-update-modtime --transfers 30 --checkers 8 --contimeout 60s --timeout 300s --retries 3 --low-level-retries 10 --stats 1s --stats-file-name-length 0 --exclude-from exclude.txt --ignore-case --log-file=rclone.log
```

**[WORKAROUND 2]**. You may dynamically modify the incorrect entry in the *exclude.txt*, without affecting any other entries. then, passing it to **--exclude-from**. You also expect to ignore cases when matching names. (option **--ignore-case**).

This would result in the following command:

```
rclone sync upload_local gdrive:upload --verbose --update --modify-window 1h --no-update-modtime --transfers 30 --checkers 8 --contimeout 60s --timeout 300s --retries 3 --low-level-retries 10 --stats 1s --stats-file-name-length 0 --exclude-from <(cat exclude.txt | sed 's/Zone.identifier/*Zone.Identifier*/') --ignore-case --log-file=rclone.log
```

**[WORKAROUND 3]**. The **--exclude-from** option indeed disregards files by matching their exact filenames. Nonetheless, you can utilize wildcards in filenames to allow for partial name matches. You aim to process a file that handles both partial names with wildcards and also full names as if they were partial names (with wildcards), without modifying the *exclude.txt* file on the disk. It is important to note that you also expect to ignore cases when matching names. (option **--ignore-case**)

One possible solution would be to modify the *exclude.txt* actively by appending wildcards at the start of lines, but only if they are not already present. Afterwards, pass this modified version to the **--exclude-form** parameter.

```
rclone sync upload_local gdrive:upload --verbose --update --modify-window 1h --no-update-modtime --transfers 30 --checkers 8 --contimeout 60s --timeout 300s --retries 3 --low-level-retries 10 --stats 1s --stats-file-name-length 0 --exclude-from <(cat exclude.txt | sed '/^\*/! s/^/*/g' ) --ignore-case --log-file=rclone.log
```

Comment: but it doesn't work with `--exclude-from`. log e.g: `2023/09/27 16:21:08 INFO  : ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe:Zone.Identifier: Copied (new)`

Comment: Thanks for the update. The problem seems pretty simple: "Zone.identifier" is declared in your exclusion file, however "Zone.Identifier" is actually written...BEWARE OF THE "I" (uppercase i). The actual file name does not match your declaration in exclude.txt... I edited my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry but keep uploading the file to gdrive, with your fix `
`--ignore-case`. the only way is by declaring in my list the full file name `ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe:Zone.Identifier` and that's not what I want, because there may be many files with different names, ending in that.

Comment: okay. Maybe it is due to a exact PATH match issue. Are you able to UPDATE your (exclude.txt) to change "Zone.identifier" to "*:Zone.Identifier" or "ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe:Zone.Identifier" , and check if the file effectively ignored from sync? Moreover, is this a valid solution, or do you expect a working rsync command WITHOUT touching the exclude.txt?

Comment: In this case, try replacing --exclude-form by --filter-form in your command. Tell me if it does any better? If it does, i will update the answer.

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148798/discussion-between-petitradisgris-and-acgbox).

Comment: Okay. First, your update seems weird. Do you do your trials with --ignore-case ? its very important, but not mentioned in your command from your post. (update it). Secondly, try the [EDIT 2] command in my answer.

Comment: What you propose with "EDIT 2" is not related to the question. It is a "workaround" with external commands. If I accepted that, I would run the following command instead and avoid the question: `find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -iregex "^.*(:encryptable|Zone\.identifier|.fuse_hidden*|goutputstream*|.spotlight-*|.fseventsd*|.ds_store*|~lock.*|Thumbs\.db|attributes:).*$" -exec rm {} \; &> /dev/null`

Comment: okay. Look at my workaround 3. I surrender if it still doesn't match your need ^^. Actually, you have to choose if you want to handle every lines as partial names, or as full names. You can't do both without manually specifying exceptions in the exceptions.